# python regular expression tag

Tags: python, regex, expression

I want to change this string

`<p><b> hello world </b></p>. I am playing <b> python </b>`

to:

`<bold><bold>hello world </bold></bold>, I am playing <bold> python </bold>`

I used:

```
import re 

pattern = re.compile(r'\<p>(.*?)\</p>|\<b>(.*?)\</b>')

print re.sub(pattern, r'<bold>\1</bold>', "<p><b>hello world</b></p>. I am playing <b> python</b>")
```

It does not output what I want, it complains error: *unmatched group*

It works in this case:

```
re.sub(pattern, r'<bold>\1</bold>', "<p>hello world</p>. I am playing <p> python</p>")
```

`<bold> hello world </bold>`. I am playing `<bold> python</bold>`

Comment: You need to read (or re-read) the Python Regexp docs. Pay special attention to the section starting, "The special sequences consist of '\' and a character from the list below."  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Use triple quotes around the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't recommend using Regex for parsing HTML (there are libraries for that purpose in almost every language), this should work:

```
text = "<p><b> hello world </b></p>. I am playing <b> python </b>"

import re 

pattern1 = re.compile(r'\<p>(.*?)\</p>')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'\<b>(.*?)\</b>')

replaced = re.sub(pattern1, r'<bold>\1</bold>', text)
replaced = re.sub(pattern2, r'<bold>\1</bold>', replaced)
```

I think the problem you're having is because of how Python takes Groups.
Test the following and you'll see what I mean:

```
text = "<p><b> hello world </b></p>. I am playing <b> python </b>"

import re 

pattern = re.compile(r'\<p>(.*?)\</p>|\<b>(.*?)\</b>')

for match in pattern.finditer(text):
  print match.groups()
```

You will see the following:

```
('<b> hello world </b>', None) # Here captured the 1st group
(None, ' python ') # Here the 2nd ;)
```

And anyway, take in count that it matched first what is between `<p></p>` so it took `<b> hello world </b>` (something you would like to match too) as the first match. Maybe changin the order of the compiled regex in `pattern` would solve this, but could happen the opposite (having `<b><p> ... </p></b>`)

I wish I could provide more info, but I'm not very good in regex using Python. C# takes them differently.

**Edit:**
I understand you might want to do this using regex for learning/testing purpose, don't know, but in production code I would go for another alternative (like the one @Senthil gave you) or just use a [HTML Parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=Python+%2B+HTML+parser).

Answer (score 5):

If you choose not to use regex, then it simple as this:

```
d = {'<p>':'<bold>','</p>':'</bold>','<b>':'<bold>','</b>':'</bold>'}
s = '<p><b> hello world </b></p>. I am playing <b> python </b>'
for k,v in d.items():
    s = s.replace(k,v)
```

Comment: Yes. It is great to do in this way. But I still want to know how to do in regular expression

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because the first group is the one within `<p></p>` and the second group is within `<b></b>` in the regexp. However, in your substitution you are referring to the first group when, if it matched to `<b></b>`, there wasn't one. I offer a couple of solutions.

First,

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'<(p|b)>(.*?)</\1>')
>>> print re.sub(pattern, r'<bold>\2</bold>', 
                 "<p><b>hello world</b></p>. I am playing <b> python</b>")
<bold><b>hello world</b></bold>. I am playing <bold> python</bold>
```

will match a given pair of tags. However, as you can see, it would have to be used twice on the string because when it matched the `<p></p>` tags, it skipped over the nested `<b></b>` tags.

Here's the option that I would go with:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'<(/?)[pb]>')
>>> print re.sub(pattern, r'<\1bold>', 
                 "<p><b>hello world</b></p>. I am playing <b> python</b>")
<bold><bold>hello world</bold></bold>. I am playing <bold> python</bold>
```

Comment: Pretty solution. Could you explain what you did in the last one with `<(/?)[pb]>`?

Comment: Great. Could you explain why r'<\1bold>'?

Comment: (/?) means that the first group contains only the a / or is an empty string because the ? means that the slash is optional. `[pb]` just means to match one character that is either p or b. r'<\1bold>' just puts that first group, the slash or empty string, back where it should be.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, but what I don't understand is in which part the `<b>` and `<p>` tags are replaced? I don't see them inside any group.

Comment: @Oscar, they don't need to be explicitly enclosed in ()'s. sub replaces the entire match. This is just the same as in the OP's match really.